# If G is a separable metrizable group with at least two elements, then $G^{\omega_1}$ is a separable Fréchet group which is not metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

> (Assuming $\mathfrak{p}>\omega_1$) If G is a separable metrizable group with at least two elements, then $G^{\omega_1}$ is a separable Fréchet group which is not metrizable.

This is stated without proof in the survey article by Justin Tatch Moore and Stevo Todorcevic in *Open Problems in Topology 2* titled *The metrization problem for Fréchet groups*.

I've never studied topological groups before and I have some questions.

How am I supposed to interpret $G^{\omega_1}$? Are its elements finite support $\omega_1$-sequences (almost always $1_G$) or just all $\omega_1$-sequences?

It would also be very useful to me if you could help me verify the claim. It has been suggested to me that this claim might actually be false and a mistake by the authors. (But this might be because of a wrong interpretation of $G^{\omega_1}$.) I'm wondering which of the three properties (separable, fréchet, non-metrizable) are always true and which need the assumption of $\mathfrak{p}>\omega_1$.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I've found the following claim which is probably what Moore and Todorcevic intended to convey with their example:

> Assuming $\mathfrak{p}>\omega_1$, every countable dense subgroup of $2^{\omega_1}$ is Fréchet and not metrizable.

This subgroup would be Fréchet and separable (both simply because it's countable), but how can I verify it's not metrizable?

Comment: I would assume it means all $\omega_1$-sequences, with the product topology.  All the properties except it being Fréchet are then standard facts (a product of $\leq\mathfrak{c}$ separable spaces is separable, and a nontrivial uncountable product cannot be metrizable).  But unless I'm making a mistake, it seems not to be Fréchet: if $a,b\in G$ are two distinct elements of $G$, then the set of functions $\omega_1\to G$ that are $a$ at countably many points and $b$ everywhere else has the constant function $a$ as a limit point, but not the limit of any sequence.

Comment: @EricWofsey I edited with some new information! Thank you for your comment, I agree your proof of it not being Fréchet seems to be correct.